# float: left; dropping child divs underneath parent

Tags: css

This is a bit complicated, and **is a Chrome specific issue** ([jsFiddle for reference](http://jsfiddle.net/Barbacoa/6qWg6/52/)).

I have some html that is a container which houses three DIVs:

- one header div (which must grow and shrink to the size of the container)
- one "child" div (which is always in the top left corner, but otherwise acts like a child div)
- and one "child-container" div that houses zero-to-many child divs (which should float left and then wrap after the fifth item)

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="header">cool header</div>

    <div class="child">child 0</div>

    <div id="child_container">
        <div class="child">child 1</div>
        <div class="child">child 2</div>
        <div class="child">child 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue that I'm having is when there are 5 or fewer "child" divs. If there are [more than 5 "child" divs](http://jsfiddle.net/Barbacoa/6qWg6/52/), everything formats properly. If there are [fewer than 5 "child" divs](http://jsfiddle.net/Barbacoa/6qWg6/54/), then the last "child" will always appear underneath the "child 0" div. What I need is the "child" divs to NOT warp to a second line until there are greater than five children.

I've tried a several different approaches (ie, different display types, floating containers, not floating all children, etc.), but no matter what I try, either the "header" class doesn't size properly or the children don't wrap properly.

Suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting this straight. You want to have at most 9 inline elements, and then when they become 10 have the last 5 to break into a second line?

Comment: I want (effectively) a line break after every fifth element. There is no upper limit.

Comment: Your demo for "fewer than 5 child divs" does not show the last child element underneath the "child 0" element, so it is hard to see what the problem is.  Please clarify.

Comment: @MarcAudet, I just realized that it's a Chrome specific issue. Works properly in Firefox and IE11.

Comment: If it were not for the `#child_container` wrapping element, you would get the desired effect... this is rather interesting... will bookmark it for later.

Answer (score 0):

[Solved Check Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6qWg6/57/)

Giving `min-width:` attrib solves the issues check the different wrap numbers
Its the Container width which dictates when it wraps you currently gives max limit

### ***EDIT***:Even though its chrome specific issue in chrome it is solved by giving `min-width:`

[image: O/p]

### [Demo Which Shows the difference with and without min-width](http://jsfiddle.net/6qWg6/60/)

[image]